# python pygame window wont close "not responding"

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a python window for my game from my laptop in pygame... however when I try to close the window I get an error message saying "not responding" im not sure why that if I thought i had done everything right.... the code is below any help is needed.
Thanks!

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,400))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
sky_surface = pygame.image.load("bg_desert.png").convert()
snail_surface = pygame.image.load("snailWalk1.png").convert_alpha()
player_surf = pygame.image.load("p1_walk01.png")

snail_x_pos = 600



while True:
    pygame.time.set_timer(snail_x_pos, 100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print("hello")
        snail_x_pos -=4
        if snail_x_pos < -100: snail_x_pos = 800
        
        screen.blit(sky_surface,(0,0))
        
        screen.blit(snail_surface,(snail_x_pos,350))

        screen.blit(player_surf,(80, 200))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: do you run it directly in system in console `python script.py` or in some `IDE`/editor? Maybe it is problem with `IDE`.

Comment: you shoulr use `set_timer` only once (before loop) and it will send event again and again all time. Now you run it in every loop so it create new process with will send event again and again. After 100 loops you have 100 processes which will send event again and again.

Comment: it seems you use snail position in `set_timer` - so you don't understand how to use it. It should be `set_time(my_event_ID, milliseconds)` and in `for event in pygame.event.get():` you shoudl check `if event.type = my_event_ID: ...code... ` and it will repeate `...code...` every time used in `set_timer`

Answer (score 1):

All problem makes

```
 pygame.time.set_timer(snail_x_pos, 100)
```

which you run inside loop.

If I remove it then it closes without problem.

Every `set_timer` creates new timer which sends `event` every `100ms` (again and again). If you run it in loop then you create hundreds timers.

You should run it only once - before loop - and it will repeatly send event which you can get in `for`-loop.

Problem is also that you use it in wrong way - you use snail position but it should `user_id` and time in milliseconds.

```
my_event_id = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(my_event_id, 500)  # 500ms = 0.5s
```

and later you can use it to move snail

```
    elif event.type == my_event_id:
        print('0.5 second')
        snail_x_pos -= 4
```

---

Here my version with other changes.

I use Surfaces instead images so everyone can simply copy and run it.

I also use `pygame.Rect` to keep position and size - it has useful values (ie. `.center` to get/set center position) and functions (ie. to detect colisions). I use `.left` and `.right` to move snake to right side of window when it leaves window on left side.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,400))

sky_surface = pygame.Surface((800, 100))
sky_surface.fill((0,0,255))
sky_surface_rect = sky_surface.get_rect()

snail_surface = pygame.Surface((100, 10))
snail_surface.fill((0,255,0))
snail_surface_rect = snail_surface.get_rect()
snail_surface_rect.x = 600
snail_surface_rect.y = 350

player_surf = pygame.Surface((10, 50))
player_surf.fill((255,0,0))
player_surf_rect = player_surf.get_rect()
player_surf_rect.x = 80
player_surf_rect.y = 200

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

my_event_id = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(my_event_id, 500)  # 500ms = 0.1s

while True:

    # - events -
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print("hello")
                
        elif event.type == my_event_id:
            print('0.5 second')
            # move snake
            snail_surface_rect.x -= 4
            
            # use this event to slow down player
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                player_surf_rect.x -= 4
            elif pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                player_surf_rect.x += 4

    # - updates -
    
    if snail_surface_rect.right < 0:
        snail_surface_rect.left = 800

    # - draw -
    
    screen.fill((0,0,0))  # clear screen
    screen.blit(sky_surface, sky_surface_rect)
    screen.blit(snail_surface, snail_surface_rect)
    screen.blit(player_surf, player_surf_rect)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```